Change TableContainer default theming chakra ui
I'm using chakra ui's TableContainer with the following style:
<TableContainer p="8" m="8" bg="white" border="6px solid" borderRadius="xl" borderColor="white" boxShadow='base'>

I want to add a default theme to it, I have tried the following:
I have this file tableContainer.js:
const TableContainer = {
    baseStyle: {
      p: "8",
      m: "8",
      bg: "white",
      border: "6px solid",
      borderRadius: "2xl",
      borderColor: "white",
      boxShadow: "base",
    },
  }
  
export default TableContainer

In my index.js I have this to set the default usage:
import { extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import TableContainer from ".tableContainer"

const overrides = {
    components: {
        TableContainer
    }
}

export default extendTheme(overrides)


My app.js has the following line it it as well:
<ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
Then just calling <TableContainer><TableContainer/>
But my styling is not applying.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated?

I have found a solution it's not perfect but it does work...
I created tableContainer.js:
import { TableContainer } from '@chakra-ui/react';

const CustomTableContainer = (props) => {
  return (
    <TableContainer
      p="5"
      m="8"
      bg="white"
      border="3px solid"
      borderRadius="2xl"
      borderColor="white"
      boxShadow="base"
      {...props}
    >
      {props.children}
    </TableContainer>
  );
};

export default CustomTableContainer;

Then just import like so:
import CustomTableContainer from "path_to_component/tableContainer";

And use as follows:
<CustomTableContainer>
    <Table>
        ... rest of you table data here
    <Table/>
<CustomTableContainer/>

Achieves the same result for making a reusable TableContainer in ChakraUI.
